# ¿Se puede hacer llamadas a metodos haciendo click en un boton en HTML5?

Tags: html, html5, método

la cuestion es que si puedo hacer llamadas a metodos para no hacer tanto codigo, debo mostrar una tabla al presionar diferentes botones.

```
 <button>Más Opciones</button>

 <button>Más Opciones</button>


<TABLE align="center">
                                    <TR>
                                        <TD>
                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                <input type="radio" name="TipoActivo" value=1>1
                                            </label>
                                        </TD>
                                        <TD>
                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                <input type="radio" name="TipoSaldo" value=1>2
                                            </label>
                                        </TD>
                                    </TR>
                                    <TR>
                                        <TD>
                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                <input type="radio" name="TipoActivo" value=2>P3
                                            </label>
                                        </TD>
                                        <TD>
                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                <input type="radio" name="TipoSaldo" value=2>7
                                            </label>
                                        </TD>
                                    </TR>
                                    <TR>
                                        <TD>
                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                <input type="radio" name="TipoActivo" value=3>8
                                            </label>
                                        </TD>
                                        <TD>
                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                <input type="radio" name="TipoSaldo" value=3>9
                                            </label>
                                        </TD>
                                    </TR>
                                </TABLE>
```

al presionar cualquiera de los dos botones me mostrara la misma tabla

Comment: Metodos JavaScript ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes llamar cualquier función de `JavaScript` colocando el atributo `onclick` en tu elemento y asignándole como valor el nombre de la función que deseas llamar, ejm:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Más Opciones</button>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Más Opciones</button>
```

Y en el javascript deberías de tener algo como:

```
function myFunction(){
    // Código de la función
}
```

**EJEMPLO FUNCIONAL CON JAVASCRIPT NATIVO**

```js
function mostrarTabla(){
    var tabla = document.querySelector("table");
    tabla.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
table{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="mostrarTabla()">Más Opciones</button>

<button onclick="mostrarTabla()">Más Opciones</button>


<table align="center">
<tr>
    <td>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="TipoActivo" value=1>1
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="TipoSaldo" value=1>2
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="TipoActivo" value=2>P3
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="TipoSaldo" value=2>7
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="TipoActivo" value=3>8
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="TipoSaldo" value=3>9
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**EJEMPLO FUNCIONAL CON JQUERY**

```js
function mostrarTabla(){
    $("table").fadeIn();
}
```

```css
table{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="mostrarTabla()">Más Opciones</button>

<button onclick="mostrarTabla()">Más Opciones</button>


<table align="center">
<tr>
    <td>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="TipoActivo" value=1>1
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="TipoSaldo" value=1>2
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="TipoActivo" value=2>P3
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="TipoSaldo" value=2>7
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="TipoActivo" value=3>8
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="TipoSaldo" value=3>9
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: **// Código de la función**   aqui debo poner el codigo de la tabla ??

Comment: @R.Fernandez no, debes poner el código que va a mostrar tu tabla, te voy a hacer el ejemplo completo funcional para que veas dame unos minutos!

Comment: ok, esperare, tienes toda mi atencion

Comment: @R.Fernandez te he editado la respuesta con dos ejemplos, uno de JavaScript nativo y otro con jQuery, espero te sirvan !

Comment: al hacer onclick activa el evento, como al hacer submit como diferenciarlos ?

Comment: @R.Fernandez no entiendo tu referencia, el submit es para botones que estén dentro de un formulario.

Comment: tengo '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i> Imprimir
                        </button>' este boton y y mi mas opciones hace la misma accion que ese boton, como decir aceptar y mandar todo al controlador

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68460/discussion-between-camilo-vasquez-and-r-fernandez).

Comment: ya estaaaaaaaaa

Answer (score 1):

En el siguiente ejemplo aprenderemos a llamar una función al momento de apretar un botón en JS.

```
<html> <head>

<script type="text/javascript"> function miFuncion() { alert("Activaste la funcion miFuncion()"); } </script>

</head> <body>

<form> <input type="button"  onclick="miFuncion()"  value="Activar Función"> </form>

<p>Presiona el botón y saldra una alerta contenida dentro de una función.</p>

</body> </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenta colocando

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Mas opciones</button>
```

para cada boton podras colocar una función especifica.

o sino

```
<button id="one">Mas opciones</button>
```

JQuery

```
$("#one").click(function(){
$("table").hide();
```

});

para mostrar una tabla especifica puede asignarle una clase y utilizar lsa funciones .hide() o .show()  de JQuery

Comment: en detallas mas el codigo, no logro entenderlo, soy nuevo